# POSIX semaphores/threads not working correctly?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, semaphore

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>

sem_t semr;

void* func(void* i)
{
    sem_wait(&semr);
    printf("\nInstance %d running",*(int*)i);
    //sem_post(&semr);
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    sem_init(&semr,0,1);
    void* (*fp)(void*);
    int s1,s2,s3,val=0;
    pthread_t t1,t2,t3;
    fp=&func;
    val=1;
    s1=pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fp,(void*)&val);
    val=2;
    s2=pthread_create(&t2,NULL,fp,(void*)&val);
    val=3;
    s3=pthread_create(&t3,NULL,fp,(void*)&val);
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t3,NULL);  
    return 0;
}
```

### This is my understanding of what happens:

The first thread(`t1`) executes successfully. The subsequent threads(`t2` and `t3`) though, are blocked, since I never `sem_post` the semaphore. The `pthread_join`s will make `main()` wait for all 3 threads to terminate.

### This is what happens:

Neither thread will output *anything*. Not even `t1`s output(see question 1 below)

### However,

removing all `pthread_join`s has a better effect in terms of what I expect:
`t1` executes successfully and the command prompt is returned.

My questions:

1. According to the sample code on [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html), `main()` should wait for `t2` and `t3` to terminate (in addition to successfully executing `t1` *and*  outputting *something*). Am I using `pthread_join` incorrectly here? What's happening?
2. Why happens to the blocked threads(`t2` and `t3`)? Are the threads forced to terminate due to `main()` returning?

Comment: Your program (once you've fixed `var` not being undeclared) does not do what you say it does. It **does** output something (a newline).

Comment: This code won't compile. `val` is never declared. Please post a complete example that exhibits your problems.

Comment: @black_station : I edited you code - added \n ..now copy this code and execute --will work fine.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yeah, sorry made the change!

Comment: Don't cast to `void*`, this is superfluous and just adding noise.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Doesn't `pthread_create` require (void*) arguments?

Comment: @black_stallion: Any pointer type can be implicitly converted to `void*`. The cast isn't necessary.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Okay. As a side note, is passing a constant like `(void*)1` okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ensure that anything you print is terminated (not followed) with a newline. `stdout` won't be flushed while `main` is blocked waiting to join your threads. When you explicitly cancel the program, again, `stdout` won't be flushed.

Comment: When I added a \n at the end of printf its work correctly, Why so ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: What do you mean correctly? My test printed "Instance 3 running" which (from the text) doesn't sound like what was intended.

Comment: The above code doesn't prints  "Instance 3 running", but if I add '\n' at end of printf() in funtc() then recompile and executes it prints "Instance 3 running". -- in my system..Why its so?

Comment: @CharlesBailey/Grijesh: note that thread `t1` will likely see its thread parameter have the value 3 (and therefore it will print "Instance 3 running") since it may not be scheduled for execution until after the third thread has been created and `val` will  have been set to `3` by then.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: adding a `'\n'` to the end of the string causes `printf()` to flush `stdio`.  Without the `'\n'` the line of text just remains in the buffer.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: `fflush(stdout)` gave me the correct result.(`t1` did get executed)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Well on my system `t1` sees `val` equal to 1. Are threads always first created and then scheduled?

Comment: @MichaelBurr : Thanks ..I understood..instead \n , if I explicitly fflush(0); than t1 prints the line  "Instance 3 running".

Comment: @black_stallion: whether `t1` prints 1, 2, or 3 depends on scheduling, how many cores are available, and who knows what else.